# Configure Maven to look at local directory while running tests

Tags: maven

We are using JBehave and while running test we need to add a local folder and jars to the classpath while running the tests.
The problem is the local folder might vary from system to system. We want the tests to run by looking at the jars installed on that system and the resources defined on that system.

How to add a dependency to maven that could change from system to system?

Comment: I think you might be able to use an environment variable. But thats just a quick idea that came into my mind.

Comment: maven newbie.. would you be able to help me with how you can hard code such a thing?

Comment: Posted it as an answer. If it's not clear ask :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables in your `pom.xml` using `${env.VARIABLE_NAME}`. If you have the path to your local folder in the pom, you could replace it by a variable. If you do so you have to set that variable on every system you execute the maven job on. I have found some guides for [linux](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-environment-variables.html) and [windows](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html) on how to do that. Hope this fits your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The test are executed by the [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/). The plugin has only one goal [surefire:test](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) and this goal supports the configuration of [additionalClasspathElements](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#additionalClasspathElements).

You can find a usage example [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html#Additional_Classpath_Elements). The example configuration on this page looks like this:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>path/to/additional/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
            <additionalClasspathElement>path/to/additional/jar</additionalClasspathElement>
          </additionalClasspathElements>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

I would go this way. To change the local folder location for each system you can use environment variables or different maven [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles).

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way to say that these additional jars are required at compile time as well?

Comment: @sethu That might be possible but I would not recommend it. If you want to create an artifact with a preproducable build you should explicit define the depedencies that are needed for the build.